# How to Change Mail in a Box Index

Tags: nginx, roundcube, mailinabox

Good day,
Sorry if this is off, but i have installed mail in a box on a vps. If a user wants to login in to use a webmail roundcube they have to go to mail.mydomain.com/mail. If a user goes to mail.mydomain.com they are not directed to the webmail roundcube. My question is that how can i make it that if a user goes to mail.mydomain.com they can see the roundcube login page enen if they don't enter the prefix /mail.

I am sure this must be in nginx but i don't know where to chnage.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you but i solved this with nginx